# Accessing Context where there is no http.Request

Tags: go

I am setting `X-Request-Id` in `context` within a middleware (*as shown below*) so that I can use it where there is `*http.Request` struct - e.g. `req.Context().Value(middleware.ReqIdKey)`. However, there are some places in my codebase where there is no way for me to access `*http.Request` struct hence reason I am not able to use `context` to fetch `X-Request-Id`. Is there a way in Go or am I trying to do something fundamentally wrong?

**internal/middleware/requestid.go**

This is middleware where I set the `X-Request-Id` in `context`. Currently called as `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", middleware.RequestId(SomeHandler))` in my "server" package.

```golang
package middleware

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "net/http"
)

type val string
const ReqIdKey val = "X-Request-Id"

func RequestId(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        val := req.Header.Get("X-Request-Id")
        if val == "" {
            val = uuid.New().String()
        }

        ctx1 := context.WithValue(req.Context(), ReqIdKey, val)
        ctx2 := req.WithContext(ctx1)

        handler.ServeHTTP(res, ctx2)
    })
}
```

**internal/logger/logger.go**

This is another package where I need to access `context` or just `X-Request-Id` value. By the way, calling `logger.Config` takes place before starting the server.

```golang
package logger

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
)

var Log *logrus.Entry

func Config() {
    logrus.SetLevel(logrus.InfoLevel)
    logrus.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})

    Log = logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "request_id": ..., // I need X-Request-Id value to go here so that all logs have it
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should pass your context everywhere it's needed.  If you need that in your `Config()` function, pass it there:

```
func Config(ctx context.Context) {
  /* ... * /
}
```

But you probably call `Config()` once, on startup, not per request, which leads to my second point:

You should not be passing context, or request-scoped data in general, to a config function. This is completely backwards.

Rather, you should be passing your logger into your handler/middleware, and let it log with the request data:

```
func handleSomePath(logger *logrus.Entry) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        /* do something */
        logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
            "request_id": /* ... */
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `But you probably call Config() once, on startup` - This is exactly the case also I configure logrus before serving the server so the solution for passing logger to where it is needed is a cleaner solution to me. I thought about it but just because I am a beginner in Go I didn't want to do a random slapdash work. Ta.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a http.Request you can access the Context and Values in there. If you do not have a Request but need the Context: Get the Context and pass it down your calltree as an explicit parameter (by convention its the first parameter).

(There is no magic in Go and any thing not passed into a function, either directly or indirectly simply is not there.)

Comment: "Get the Context.." - Do you mean create one manually right at the beginning of the application boot? e.g. `context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)`, `defer cancel()` and pass it to, for example, server.

Comment: No... get the context from the request:  `ctx := req.Context()`